# Error argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint8_t

Tags: arrays, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

This is my first time coding. I just learned some stuff from youtube.com and this is the first time I am using that knowledge to write a an arduino sketch for my micro-controller. Please go easy on me.

The problem I am getting is this:

> **argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint8_t"**

It's in the OUTPUT array declaration.

[image: Error Screenshot]
[Error areas 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGRX3.png)
[Error area 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzDkY.png)

```
//https://codeshare.io/GA9YDl
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>                                     // this AVR library contains the methods that controls the sleep modes

bool RSTstate = 0;
  //Inputs and their Variables
  bool J5 = 19;                          //J5 is also an boolerrupt so we are going to be using that as one too.
  bool j5state;
  
  
  //Inputs PULLUPs
  bool S3 = 0;
  bool S1 = 1;
  bool S1state;
  bool S3state;
  
  //Momentary PULLUPs
  bool J1 = 17;
  bool j1state;

  //Analog Inputs
  int J3in = 2;
  int J3state;
  
  //Momentary OUTPUTs 
  bool J4 = 14;
  bool J3out = 18;

  //OUTPUTs
  int C1[4] = {10, 11, 13, 4};
  int C2[3] = {11, 12, 4};
  int C3[2] = {10, 4};
  int C4[1] = {9};
  int C5[1] = {8};
  


void goingToSleep() {
  sleep_enable();                                          // enabling sleep mode
  attachInterrupt(j5state, wakeUp, LOW);                   // attaching to boolerrupt J5 (INTERRUPT_PIN) the function wakeUp to be triggered when get LOW signal... Also J5 LOW means plugged IN.
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);                     // setting the sleep mode, in our case full sleep
  sleep_cpu();                                             // activating sleep mode
}

void wakeUp() {
  Serial.println("interrrupt Fired!");                     // print message to serial monitor
  sleep_disable();                                         // disable sleep mode
  detachInterrupt(j5state);                               // removes the boolerrupt from J5
  softreset();              //Now needs to reset the mcu as the jack is plugged in.
  RSTstate = 1;      //Set Reset State to 1 so that the MCU restarts the sketch
}

void softreset() {
  asm volatile ("  jmp 0");    //Just restart the sketch, does not reset the registers etc.
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(J5, INPUT);
  pinMode(S3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(S1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(J1, INPUT);
  pinMode(J3in, INPUT);
  pinMode(C1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //First turn off every output
  digitalWrite(C1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C5, LOW);
  //This is the first phase: To check if the headphone plug is connected or not.
  pinMode(J4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(J4, LOW);
  delay(5);
  j5state = digitalRead(J5);
  if (j5state == LOW) { //That means that the 3.5mm plug is put in.
    //Here the second phase starts where we need to check the connectivity of S1 and S3.
    pinMode(J4, INPUT);       //Fisrt setup the J4 to INPUT so that it does not boolerface with the Audio.
    S1state = digitalRead(S1);
    S3state = digitalRead(S3);
    if (S1state == HIGH && S3state == LOW) { //This means that Condition 1, 2 and 3 applies.
      //Here is the 3rd phase starts where we have to check the conditions for C1, C2 and C3
      //First C1 where we have to check for J1 and J2 connectivity. J2 is Hardware GND and J1 is mic input which is boolernal PULLUP.
      pinMode(J1, INPUT_PULLUP);
      delay(5);
      j1state = digitalRead(J1);
      if (j1state == LOW) {
        //This is where the C1 condition is TRUE and is executed
        digitalWrite(C1, HIGH);
      }
      else if (j1state == HIGH) {
        //That means C1 is not meeting requirements and thus C2 is now checked
        //To check C2 we need to check between J3 and J4 and the easy way to do that is to just check an analog value for J3 to GND.
                pinMode(J3in, INPUT);
                pinMode(J3out, OUTPUT);
                delay(5);
                digitalWrite(J3out, HIGH);
                delay(5);
                J3state = analogRead(J3in);
                pinMode(J3out, INPUT);
                if (J3state > 15) {
                    //That means that J3 is not connected to GND. Which means there is a speaker attached. That means C2 is applied.
                    digitalWrite(C2, HIGH);
                }
                else if (J3state < 15) {
                  //That means that J3 is directly connected to GND which also means that there is no speaker attached.
                  //So now C3 is applied.
                  digitalWrite(C3, HIGH);
                }
                else {
                  Serial.println("ERROR C2, C3");
                }
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("ERROR C1");
      }
    }
    else if (S1state == LOW && S3state == HIGH) {
      //Now the S1 is turned ON and thus we only need to check Condition 4 (C4) and C5.
      //First C4, for C4 we need the connection between J3 and GND. Same method as C2 and C3.
      pinMode(J3out, OUTPUT);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(J3out, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      J3state == analogRead(J3in);
      pinMode(J3out, INPUT);
      if (J3state > 15) {
        //That means J3 is not connected to GND. Which applied C4.
        digitalWrite(C4, HIGH);
      }
      else if (J3state < 15) {
        //Now the condition is set to C5
        digitalWrite(C5, HIGH);
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("ERROR C4, C5");
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("ERROR S1, S3");
    }
  }
  else if (j5state == HIGH) {
    goingToSleep();    
    //This loop is for when there is no jack, the microcontroller can just
    //wait for the plug to be inserted. But also in some kind of sleepmode to conserve power.    
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("ERROR JACK");
  }
  }
//All of the above process is done in the setup loop since it does not needs to be repeated. Only run once.


void loop() {
  if (RSTstate == 1){
    softreset();
  }
  else {
    goingToSleep();     //Once everything is executed succesfully. Here the microcontroller goes into sleep mode and will only wake up if the jack is plugged IN again.
  }
}
```

Comment: Please confirm which line numbers the errors are implicating, since your code is not numbered. Your `main()` is missing too, so this isn't a minimal reproducible example. Also, _please_ consider (a) splitting up such monolithic functions into smaller ones, (b) not using so many global variables if they don't have legit reasons to be global (few do), and (c) exiting early in error cases, instead of doing that awful ever-increasing `if`/`else` indentation pyramid of doom.

Comment: Learn your datatypes.  They are likely incompatible, just as the error says.

Comment: @TomServo: If you are talking about the data types for the variables of Pins then yes you are correct and I changed them. But this error only occured with the Array under the //OUTPUTs. Now that I have removed the arrays its good.

Answer (score 1):

The types are incorrect in many of the definitions:

```
bool J5 = 19;
...
bool J1 = 17;
...
int J3in = 2;
int J3state;

bool J4 = 14;
bool J3out = 18;

int C1[4] = {10, 11, 13, 4};
int C2[3] = {11, 12, 4};
int C3[2] = {10, 4};
int C4[1] = {9};
int C5[1] = {8};
```

The `xxstate` indicators should have type `bool`, while the other declarations should have type `uint8_t`.

Comment: I tried using uint_8 but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: @IMFROST `bool` is definitely wrong for `J5` and `J4` given the initial value. Do you get other errors after modifying the types?

Comment: Ok now I realize that bool for J5 and J1 and others like it is a bad idea.

Comment: Also I don't get any other errors. And this is not an error as the compiler does successfully compiles it but this is shown as a warning

Comment: @IMFROST: just look at the lines for which the warnings are reported: one of the expressions in each of those lines has type `int` where the corresponding argument of the function call is defined as `uint8_t`. It is not per se an error, but the compiler warns you that this implicit conversion may change the `int` value if it is outside the range of type `uint8_t` (`0`..`255`)

Comment: So everything is good then, except changing those bool values to int.

Comment: @IMFROST: It is good practice to let the compiler issue warnings for many potential bugs and to fix these warnings by changing the code and make it cleaner and safer. You did not post enough information to determine which function calls are flagged, but you should try and modify the code so it compiles cleanly.

Comment: Ok I am going to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the modified code. It solved the previous issue (probably because I discarded the array, which is not a solution, but it worked for me).

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>                                     // this AVR library contains the methods that controls the sleep modes

bool RSTstate = 0;
  //Inputs and their Variables
  int J5 = 19;                          //J5 is also an boolerrupt so we are going to be using that as one too.
  bool j5state;
  
  
  //Inputs PULLUPs
  const int S3 = 0;
  const int S1 = 1;
  bool S1state;
  bool S3state;
  
  //Momentary PULLUPs
  const int J1 = 17;
  bool j1state;

  //Analog Inputs
  const int J3in = 2;
  int J3state;
  
  //Momentary OUTPUTs 
  const int J4 = 14;
  const int J3out = 18;

  //OUTPUTs
  const int C123 = 4;
  const int C1 = 13;
  const int C12 = 11;
  const int C13 = 10;
  const int C2 = 12;
  const int C4 = 9;
  const int C5 = 8;

  /*
  int C1[4] = {10, 11, 13, 4};
  int C2[3] = {11, 12, 4};
  int C3[2] = {10, 4};
  int C4[1] = {9};
  int C5[1] = {8};
  */


void goingToSleep() {
  sleep_enable();                                          // enabling sleep mode
  attachInterrupt(j5state, wakeUp, LOW);                   // attaching to boolerrupt J5 (INTERRUPT_PIN) the function wakeUp to be triggered when get LOW signal... Also J5 LOW means plugged IN.
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);                     // setting the sleep mode, in our case full sleep
  sleep_cpu();                                             // activating sleep mode
}

void wakeUp() {
  Serial.println("boolerrrupt Fired!");                     // print message to serial monitor
  sleep_disable();                                         // disable sleep mode
  detachInterrupt(j5state);                               // removes the boolerrupt from J5
  softreset();              //Now needs to reset the mcu as the jack is plugged in.
}

void softreset() {
  asm volatile ("  jmp 0");    //Just restart the sketch, does not reset the registers etc.
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(J5, INPUT);
  pinMode(S3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(S1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(J1, INPUT);
  pinMode(J3in, INPUT);
  pinMode(C1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C123, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //First turn off every output
  digitalWrite(C1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C12, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C123, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C13, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C5, LOW);
  //This is the first phase: To check if the headphone plug is connected or not.
  pinMode(J4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(J4, LOW);
  delay(5);
  j5state = digitalRead(J5);
  if (j5state == LOW) { //That means that the 3.5mm plug is put in.
    //Here the second phase starts where we need to check the connectivity of S1 and S3.
    pinMode(J4, INPUT);       //Fisrt setup the J4 to INPUT so that it does not boolerface with the Audio.
    S1state = digitalRead(S1);
    S3state = digitalRead(S3);
    if (S1state == HIGH && S3state == LOW) { //This means that Condition 1, 2 and 3 applies.
      //Here is the 3rd phase starts where we have to check the conditions for C1, C2 and C3
      //First C1 where we have to check for J1 and J2 connectivity. J2 is Hardware GND and J1 is mic input which is boolernal PULLUP.
      pinMode(J1, INPUT_PULLUP);
      delay(5);
      j1state = digitalRead(J1);
      if (j1state == LOW) {
        //This is where the C1 condition is TRUE and is executed
        digitalWrite(C1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C123, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C12, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C13, HIGH);
      }
      else if (j1state == HIGH) {
        //That means C1 is not meeting requirements and thus C2 is now checked
        //To check C2 we need to check between J3 and J4 and the easy way to do that is to just check an analog value for J3 to GND.
                pinMode(J3in, INPUT);
                pinMode(J3out, OUTPUT);
                delay(5);
                digitalWrite(J3out, HIGH);
                delay(5);
                J3state = analogRead(J3in);
                pinMode(J3out, INPUT);
                if (J3state > 15) {
                    //That means that J3 is not connected to GND. Which means there is a speaker attached. That means C2 is applied.
                    digitalWrite(C2, HIGH);
                    digitalWrite(C123, HIGH);
                    digitalWrite(C12, HIGH);
                }
                else if (J3state < 15) {
                  //That means that J3 is directly connected to GND which also means that there is no speaker attached.
                  //So now C3 is applied.
                  digitalWrite(C123, HIGH);
                  digitalWrite(C13, HIGH);
                }
                else {
                  Serial.println("ERROR C2, C3");
                }
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("ERROR C1");
      }
    }
    else if (S1state == LOW && S3state == HIGH) {
      //Now the S1 is turned ON and thus we only need to check Condition 4 (C4) and C5.
      //First C4, for C4 we need the connection between J3 and GND. Same method as C2 and C3.
      pinMode(J3out, OUTPUT);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(J3out, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      J3state == analogRead(J3in);
      pinMode(J3out, INPUT);
      if (J3state > 15) {
        //That means J3 is not connected to GND. Which applied C4.
        digitalWrite(C4, HIGH);
      }
      else if (J3state < 15) {
        //Now the condition is set to C5
        digitalWrite(C5, HIGH);
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("ERROR C4, C5");
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("ERROR S1, S3");
    }
  }
  else if (j5state == HIGH) {
    goingToSleep();    
    //This loop is for when there is no jack, the microcontroller can just
    //wait for the plug to be inserted. But also in some kind of sleepmode to conserve power.    
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("ERROR JACK");
  }
  }
//All of the above process is done in the setup loop since it does not needs to be repeated. Only run once.


void loop() {
  if (RSTstate == 1){
    softreset();
  }
  else {
    goingToSleep();     //Once everything is executed succesfully. Here the microcontroller goes boolo sleep mode and will only wake up if the jack is plugged IN again.
  }
}
```